# Rails 4 - delete on polymorphic attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have an articles model and a comments model.

The associations are:

article.rb

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

In my articles show view, I have:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="intpol3" style="text-align: left; margin-left:60px; padding-top:50px">
                   <%= safe_join(@article.body.split("\r\n"), "<br />".html_safe) %>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!-- placeholder for tags -->
            </div>  

        </div>

         <!-- if @article.user.full_name.present?  -->
           <!-- <div class="indexsubtext"> @article.user.full_name </div> -->
         <!-- end  -->
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="formminor" style="margin-bottom:5%">
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>  |
                    <%= link_to 'More from the blog', articles_path %>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <%= render :partial => 'comments/form', locals: {commentable: @article}  %>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                 <div class="intpol3">

                     <%= render :partial => 'comments/display', locals: {commentable: @article} %>

                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

In my comments display partial, I have:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
        <% commentable.comments.each do | comment | %>
            <div class="well">
                <%= comment.opinion %>
                <div class="commentattributionname">
                    <%= comment.user.full_name %>
                </div>
                <div class="commentattributiontitle">
                    <%= comment.user.formal_title %>
                </div>
                <div class="commentattributiondate">
                    <%= comment.created_at.try(:strftime, '%e %B %Y') %>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-xs-1">
                <%= button_to 'Delete', commentable.comment, :method => :delete %>
             </div>
        <% end %>
```

This was all working ok, until I tried to add a button to remove a comment. The comments model is polymorphic.

I have two controllers for comments (following the gorails.com tutorial), the first is articles::comments controller, which has:

```
class Articles::CommentsController < CommentsController

before_action :set_commentable#, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end
end
```

The second is comments controller which has:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
  @comment = Comment.new comment_params
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.commentable = @commentable

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

   def destroy
      @comment.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to data_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end


  private


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:opinion)
    end
end
```

I want to try to delete the comment - not the article. When I try this the error message says that the destroy action in the comments controller is the problem.

The destroy action in the article controller is:

```
def destroy
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The error message is:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticlesController#destroy
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

The respond_to line is highlighted. I don't know what these words mean - they are inserted automatically when you create a controller using scaffolding. However, I have added a respond to format to the controller as:

```
respond_to :html, :son
```

I'm not sure why my attempt to delete a comment is being directed to the destroy action in the article controller.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two controllers for comments (`Articles::Comments` & `Comments`); you should stick with `Articles::Comments` and nest it under `Articles` in the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
   resources :comments, module: :articles #-> url.com/articles/:article_id/comments/:id
end 

#app/controllers/articles/comments_controller.rb
class Articles::CommentsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_commentable

   def destroy
      @comment = @article.comments.find params[:id]
      @comment.destroy
   end

   private

   def set_commentable
      @article = Article.find params[:article_id]
   end 
end
```

This should allow you to use the following routes:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', [commentable, comment], method: :delete %>
```

--

I think you're getting confused with [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) -- whenever you set routes which are nested under others, you have the opportunity to pass both the "parent" and "child" resource to your routes.

This works in `form_for` as well as `link_to` / `button_to` -- you have to pass `["parent.id", "child.id"]` in order for the nested route to work correctly.

-

Another good trick is to use [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html), which will automatically set the routes depending on the objects you pass. I've not used it much, but seems like something you could benefit from in this instance:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', polymorphic_path([commentable, comment]), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: The reasons for having two controllers are outlined in the gorails video at: https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations?autoplay=1. I think your comments might indicate a stylistic difference of approach. Thanks for the tip on polymorphic_path. I'll explore that to see if I can figure out a solution to my issue with that idea.

Comment: Might want to look at [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I don't think there is repetition in this. Thanks anyway.